# How to iterate over fields (names + types) of a tuple/object in a macro?

Tags: nim-lang

I want to write macro which has to perform some logic based on the fields of a named tuple or object. I assume this is best accomplished by passing the tuple/object as a `typed` parameter to the macro.

The question is, how can I iterate over the fields of a `typed` parameter in general? I'm basically looking for the equivalent of `fieldPairs` for macros, i.e., instead of taking a concrete tuple/object it would have to operate on `NimNode` and also return the field names/types as such (for further AST generation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem, which seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if there are better alternatives. The solution is based on using `getTypeImpl` on the `typed` parameter. To see how it works it helps to look at the output of `t.getTypeImpl.treeRepr` for a simple tuple and object.

- **Tuple**: The type impl AST of for instance `(x: 0, y: 1, name: "")` would look something like this:

  ```
  TupleTy
    IdentDefs
      Sym "x"
      Sym "int"
      Empty
    IdentDefs
      Sym "y"
      Sym "int"
      Empty
    IdentDefs
      Sym "name"
      Sym "string"
      Empty
  ```

  Note: the `typeKind` of `getTypeImpl` is `ntyTuple`
- **Object**: The type impl AST of an object with identical structure would be:

  ```
  ObjectTy
    Empty
    Empty
    RecList
      IdentDefs
        Sym "x"
        Sym "int"
        Empty
      IdentDefs
        Sym "y"
        Sym "int"
        Empty
      IdentDefs
        Sym "name"
        Sym "string"
        Empty
  ```

  Note: the `typeKind` of `getTypeImpl` is `ntyObject`

This shows that the information we are looking for is available in the `IdentDefs`. We only have to make sure to handle tuples and objects appropriately: For a tuple the `IdentDefs` are the direct children of the `NimNode`, whereas for an object the `IdentDefs` are stored in the child on index 2 (the child on index 0 contains pragma information, child on index 1 is information on the parent).

Overall a macro could look like (with some debug output added for illustration):

```nim
macro iterateFields*(t: typed): untyped =
  echo "--------------------------------"

  # check type of t
  var tTypeImpl = t.getTypeImpl
  echo tTypeImpl.len
  echo tTypeImpl.kind
  echo tTypeImpl.typeKind
  echo tTypeImpl.treeRepr

  case tTypeImpl.typeKind:
  of ntyTuple:
    # For a tuple the IdentDefs are top level, no need to descent
    discard
  of ntyObject:
    # For an object we have to descent to the nnkRecList
    tTypeImpl = tTypeImpl[2]
  else:
    error "Not a tuple or object"

  # iterate over fields
  for child in tTypeImpl.children:
    if child.kind == nnkIdentDefs:
      let field = child[0] # first child of IdentDef is a Sym corresponding to field name
      let ftype = child[1] # second child is type
      echo "Iterating field: " & $field & " -> " & $ftype
    else:
      echo "Unexpected kind: " & child.kind.repr
      # Note that this can happen for an object with a case
      # fields, which would give a child of type nnkRecCase.
      # How to handle them depends on the use case.

# small test
type
  TestObj = object
    x: int
    y: int
    name: string

let t = (x: 0, y: 1, name: "")
let o = TestObj(x: 0, y: 1, name: "")

iterateFields(t)
iterateFields(o)
```